# Error regeneratorRuntime is not defined with Babel 7

Tags: node.js, electron, babeljs

I would like update my Babel config to version 7 in Electron project.

I've add my all plugins i needed :

```
"devDependencies": {
    "@babel/cli": "^7.0.0-beta.40",
    "@babel/core": "^7.0.0-beta.40",
    "@babel/node": "^7.0.0-beta.40",
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties": "^7.0.0-beta.40",
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-decorators": "^7.0.0-beta.40",
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-object-rest-spread": "^7.0.0-beta.40",
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-optional-chaining": "^7.0.0-beta.40",
    "@babel/plugin-transform-async-to-generator": "^7.0.0-beta.40",
    "@babel/polyfill": "^7.0.0-beta.40",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.0.0-beta.40",
    "@babel/preset-react": "^7.0.0-beta.40",
    "babel-eslint": "^7.1.1",
```

The compilation is good, but when Electron run my `main.js` (compiled), i've this error :

`A JavaScript error occurred in the main process
Uncaught Exception:
ReferenceError: regeneratorRuntime is not defined`

I've try to install `regeneratorRuntime` module, but no result.

Answer (score 25):

You should import the Babel Polyfill in your code:

```
import "@babel/polyfill";
```

Comment: Where, exactly?

Comment: @hecontreraso At the top of the main file.

Comment: but why would you import that?

Comment: after or before compile?

Answer (score 1):

hey I ran into the same problem and I am using Babel 7, for me I installed these two dependencies:

```
npm install --save @babel/runtime
npm install --save-dev @babel/plugin-transform-runtime
```

And, in .babelrc, add:

```
 {
    "presets": ["@babel/preset-env"],
    "plugins": [
        ["@babel/transform-runtime"]
    ]
   }
```

**and this solved my problem**

Answer (score 0):

I had to add `@babel/plugin-transform-runtime` and set `runtimeHelpers: true`.

rollup.config.js

```
import commonjs from 'rollup-plugin-commonjs';
import resolve from 'rollup-plugin-node-resolve';
import babel from 'rollup-plugin-babel';
import pkg from './package.json';

const extensions = [
    '.js', '.jsx', '.ts', '.tsx',
];

const name = 'RollupTypeScriptBabel';

export default {
    input: './src/index.ts',

    // Specify here external modules which you don't want to include in your bundle (for instance: 'lodash', 'moment' etc.)
    // https://rollupjs.org/guide/en#external-e-external
    external: [...Object.keys(pkg.dependencies || {})],

    plugins: [
        // Allows node_modules resolution
        resolve({extensions}),

        // Allow bundling cjs modules. Rollup doesn't understand cjs
        commonjs(),

        // Compile TypeScript/JavaScript files
        babel({extensions, include: ['src/**/*'], runtimeHelpers: true}),
    ],

    output: [{
        file: pkg.main,
        format: 'cjs',
    }, {
        file: pkg.module,
        format: 'es',
    }],
};
```

.babelrc

```
{
    "presets": [
        "@babel/env",
        "@babel/typescript"
    ],
    "plugins": [
        "@babel/plugin-transform-runtime",
        "@babel/proposal-class-properties",
        "@babel/proposal-object-rest-spread"
    ]
}
```

https://github.com/codeBelt/generate-template-files

https://github.com/a-tarasyuk/rollup-typescript-babel

Answer (score 0):

for me I used this in the transpiled code for successful run :

`require("@babel/polyfill");`